# Save attachement to email using macro in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I would like to create a rule which run the following script:

```
Public Sub SaveToDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat

dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")

saveFolder = "c:\temp\"

objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & ".xls"

Set objAtt = Nothing

End Sub
```

This should save the attachment to the c:\temp folder but it does not work because objAtt value is nothing. For some reasons the line:

```
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
```

does not assign the attachment to the obAtt variable for a reason I can't figure it out. Here the attachment is a .csv file.

I am using outlook 2016 on windows 10. I would be glad to get any advice on why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the object, because you where just creating it, not filling it.

So it had no clue it was supposed to be in any relation with the MailItem.

Further more, there is a collection of Attachement to go through, see :

```
Public Sub SaveToDisk(ItM As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttS As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat

dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
saveFolder = "c:\temp\"

Set oAttS = ItM.Attachments

For Each objAtt In oAttS
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & "_" & objAtt.FileName 
Next objAtt

Set oAttS = Nothing
Set objAtt = Nothing

End Sub
```